# Find $Y=f(X)$ such that $Y \sim \text{Uniform}(-1,1)$.

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation

> If $X_1,X_2\sim \text{Normal} (0,1)$, then find $Y=f(X)$ such that $Y \sim \text{Uniform}(-1,1)$.

I solve problems where transformation is given and I need to find the distribution. But here I need to find the transformation. I have  no idea how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Can't you just pick f(X)=0.2 (for $X\in[-1,1]$, otherwise 0), since Y doesn't depend on X? (consider the graph of the pdf for Y)

Comment: @Zen: I think you are right. But I think here we need to use $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: @A.D Excellent remark. Then why on earth did you accept (less than *one hour* after the question was posted...) a solution which does not use them?

Comment: @Did: You are right. I was not careful to accept an answer.Thank you for your answer. It's very appropriate to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of this classical homework is to exhibit a usual function $f$ such that $f(X_1,X_2)$ has the desired distribution (in this context, the CDF of a gaussian random variable is not considered as a *usual* function).

To do so, recall (or reprove) that the radius $R=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ of a planar standard normal random variable $(X_1,X_2)$ has density $r\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}$ on $r\geqslant0$. A consequence is that $\mathrm e^{-R^2/2}$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, hence a solution to the question asked is
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=2\mathrm e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)/2}-1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the probability integral transform?
Note that if 
$$
  F(x)
= \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} du
$$
then $F(X_i) \sim U(0,1)$. So you could take $f(x) = 2*F(x) - 1$.

Comment: Actually, $F(x)$ should be the cumulative distribution function $\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2} dt$, not the density function.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative distribution function $F(X)$ for any random variable $X$ always have a $U(0,1)$ distribution. Hence, $2F(X)-1$ will always follow $U(-1,1)$ distribution.

Regards
Nicola Bradshaw
http://tutorteddy.com/site/free_statistics_help.php